# What are ListViewItemExpanded and GridViewItemExpanded styles for?

Tags: xaml, uwp

On Windows 10, the `generic.xaml` file for UWP apps is available for reference in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\DesignTime\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\UAP\10.0.x.0\Generic` folder, where `x` refers to the installed SDKs' versions.  Within this file, I've come across the `ListViewItemExpanded` and `GridViewItemExpanded` styles.  These are included in addition to the default styles for `ListViewItem` and `GridViewItem`.

Neither [`ListViewItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewitem) nor [`GridViewItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridviewitem) has an `IsExpanded` property, nor do their docs mention "expand", so when and how are these styles applied?

Answer (score 1):

The *default* styles for ListViewItem & GridViewItem contain a special element called `ListViewItemPresenter`. It's mainly designed for providing better UI virtualization.

Here is a more detailed explaination from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/optimize-gridview-and-listview).

> The default control templates for ListViewItem and GridViewItem
>   contain a ListViewItemPresenter element. This presenter is a single
>   optimized element that displays complex visuals for focus, selection,
>   and other visual states. If you already have custom item control
>   templates (ItemContainerStyle), or if in future you edit a copy of an
>   item control template, then we recommend you use a
>   ListViewItemPresenter because that element will give you optimum
>   balance between performance and customizability in the majority of
>   cases.

The *Expanded* styles are the traditional ways of styling list items, where you have full control over everything, such as changing the duration of the `PointerOver` transition duration.

To summarise, if you don't have too many items in your list and want to style each item in your own way, go ahead and use the expanded ones; otherwise, try to stick with the default ones that contain the `ListViewItemPresenter`.

### When are expanded styles applied?

When the `ItemsPanel` of the `ListView`/`GridView` is neither `ItemsStackPanel` nor `ItemsWrapGrid`, the UI virtualization will not work and the expanded styles will be applied automatically.

> When the ListView's ItemsPanel is not an ItemsStackPanel (the default) or 
>   ItemsWrapGrid, this template is used to show the data items. This
>   template uses a UIElement tree and visual states instead of a
>   ListViewItemPresenter.

You can read more from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx).